# I need to use data from one CSV to write data from another CSV to it

Tags: python, csv, url-rewriting

I am having trouble/am new to trying to get this to work for me smoothly using pycharm. I have one CSV that records a Date/Time and barometric pressure every single hour. I have a another CSV file that records Date/Time and water level every ten minutes.

For my task, I need to adjust/compensate the water level data using barometric pressure, and in order to do this I will need to associate the hourly Barometric data to each of the corresponding ten minute water level readings using a script:

Pressure CSV

```
date, time, pressure    
7/31/2021, 1200, 1013   
7/31/2021, 1300, 1012.5  
7/31/2021, 1400, 1013.4
7/31/2021, 1500, 1014   
7/31/2021, 1600, 1016
```

Water Level CSV

```
date, time, depth
7/31/2021, 1200, 34.55
7/31/2021, 1210, 34.56
7/31/2021, 1220, 34.55
...
7/31/2021, 1540, 36.75
7/31/2021, 1550, 36.77
7/31/2021, 1600, 36.78
```

I am trying to get the Water Level CSV to read the Pressure CSV for matching date, and matching time (but only the hour, minutes dont matter since pressure is recoded hourly), and then create anew column and write the corresponding pressure like so

New Water Level CSV

```
date, time, depth, pressure
    7/31/2021, 1200, 34.55, 1013   
    7/31/2021, 1210, 34.56, 1013   
    7/31/2021, 1220, 34.55, 1013   
    ...
    7/31/2021, 1540, 36.75, 1014
    7/31/2021, 1550, 36.77, 1014
    7/31/2021, 1600, 36.78, 1016
```

I will need to perform additional tasks after that but it is easy to do in excel using formulas once the pressures are lined up properly, wouldnt be bad for small data sets to manually go in and change but I have months of data being recorded at 10min intervals so it can get quite time consuming. Let me know your thoughts and Ill try and answer any additional questions

Comment: Hi @Wolffetti, welcome to SO. It would be helpful to people looking into your question if you would reduce it to a simpler case that is still explaining the approach to you. Maybe you want to "match rows in two different csv files"? "merge two csv files based on date, time keys"? in fact if you formulate it this way you will likely discover similar question already answered. One more thing: please mention what approaches you have already tried to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to first load all of the available pressure entries into a dictionary based on the datetime. This would then allow you to look up each value.

Next read in the level rows. Remove the `hour` value to allow you to look up the corresponding pressure. Combine the two and write to the output csv file.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

# Load all available pressures into a dictionary
pressure = {}

with open('pressure.csv') as f_pressure:
    csv_pressure = csv.reader(f_pressure)
    header = next(csv_pressure)
    
    for row in csv_pressure:
        pressure[datetime.strptime(f'{row[0]} {row[1]}', '%m/%d/%Y %H%M')] = row[2]
        
with open('waterlevel.csv') as f_level, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_level = csv.reader(f_level)
    header = next(csv_level)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["date", "time", "depth", "pressure"])
    
    for row in csv_level:
        dt = datetime.strptime(f'{row[0]} {row[1]}', '%m/%d/%Y %H%M').replace(minute=0)
        csv_output.writerow([*row, pressure[dt]])
```

For the data given, this would give you:

```
date,time,depth,pressure
7/31/2021,1200,34.55,1013
7/31/2021,1210,34.56,1013
7/31/2021,1220,34.55,1013
7/31/2021,1540,36.75,1014
7/31/2021,1550,36.77,1014
7/31/2021,1600,36.78,1016
```

If a suitable pressure value is not available, you will have to add code to perhaps use the previously available entry.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the... *key*  to this problem is creating a common key between the two data points: the date and the hour of the day (since pressure's time is the less-precise value between the two).

I also fully described the intermediate data structure that will hold the joined data before it's written back out to a CSV.  I saw one pressure with multiple depth values associated with it.

```py
import csv

from datetime import datetime


# The key that combines the two
dt_fmt  = f'%m/%d/%Y %H%M'  # datetime coming in
key_fmt = f'%Y-%m-%dT%H'    # datetime key (hour-only, so pressure & depth match)
def get_combine_key(date, time):
    dt_str = date + ' ' + time  # string concatenate
    dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, dt_fmt)
    key = dt.strftime(key_fmt)
    return key


# Aggregator...
combined_data = {}

# ...basically will look like:
#
# {
#   2021-07-03T12: {
#     pressure: 1013,
#     depth_rows: [
#       [7/31/2021, 1200, 34.55],
#       [7/31/2021, 1210, 34.56],
#       [7/31/2021, 1220, 34.55]
#     ]
#   }
# }


# Initialize combined_data: create keys with pressures and empty lists for depths
with open('pressure.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header

    for row in reader:
        date, time, pressure = row
        key = get_combine_key(date, time)
        combined_data[key] = {'pressure': pressure, 'depth_rows': []}


# Fill combineded_data: matching keys, filling lists with rows of depths
with open('depth.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        date, time, depth = row
        key = get_combine_key(date, time)
        combined_data[key]['depth_rows'].append(row)


# Print
with open('combined.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(combined_header)

    keys = sorted(combined_data.keys())  # string sort, will end up in datetime order

    # Un-pack depths, appending pressure
    for key in keys:
        datum = combined_data[key]
        pressure = datum['pressure']
        for depth_row in datum['depth_rows']:  # depth rows still in original (datetime) order
            writer.writerow(depth_row + [pressure])
```